# How to prevent replacing previous occurrences?

Tags: string, csv, replace, powershell-3.0

I am using PowerShell to replace specific strings in text/CSV file. Everything is good except one string is within other strings.

More context, in the CSV there is one field with only the word 'creator' in it. This is the field I need to change. But there are also other fields where the word 'creator' is part of a phrase.

Example

I am replacing like so:

```
(Get-Content test.csv) | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Replace('IPTC - Creator', 'XMP:Creator').Replace('Creator', 'XMP:ArtworkCreator')
} | Set-Content test2.txt
```

The word 'creator' is within other strings as stated, and its causing the second `.Replace()` call to change things I don't want changed.

In this example 'IPTC - Creator' becomes 'IPTC - XMP:ArtWorkCreator'.

Is there a way to replace the word 'creator' with 'XMP:ArtworkCreator'  without effecting the other phrases? Maybe I have to make an `if` statement?

Comment: Import the CSV with `Import-Csv`, export it with `Export-Csv`, and call `Replace()` only on the fields where you actually want something replaced.

Comment: Thank you. I had not yet learned of Import-Csv. I was playing around with it but couldnt get the correct results though. Will keep researching.